# Only 1 word from the array is being used in my Word Search generator

Tags: python, tkinter

I saw a word search game tutorial on youtube that made a word search in the python console and I tried to take that into tkinter. I have it working... sort of. The problem is that only 1 word from the possible 5 is being used in the GUI/Program. This isn't a problem in the console version so I will link both version of code. Thanks in advance for any help!

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import string

handle = open('dictionary.txt')
words = handle.readlines()
handle.close()

grid_size = 10

words = [ random.choice(words).upper().strip() \
            for _ in range(5) ]

print ("The words are:")
print(words)

grid = [ [ '_' for _ in range(grid_size) ] for _ in range(grid_size) ]

orientations = [ 'leftright', 'updown', 'diagonalup', 'diagonaldown' ]

class Label(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs, font=("Courier", 44))
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_click)

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        for row in range(grid_size):
            for column in range(grid_size):
                for word in words:
                    word_length = len(word)
                    placed = False
                while not placed:
                    orientation = random.choice(orientations)

                    if orientation == 'leftright':
                        step_x = 1
                        step_y = 0
                    if orientation == 'updown':
                        step_x = 0
                        step_y = 1
                    if orientation == 'diagonalup':
                        step_x = 1
                        step_y = -1
                    if orientation == 'diagonaldown':
                        step_x = 1
                        step_y = 1

                    x_position = random.randrange(grid_size)
                    y_position = random.randrange(grid_size)

                    ending_x = x_position + word_length*step_x
                    ending_y = y_position + word_length*step_y

                    if ending_x < 0 or ending_x >= grid_size: continue
                    if ending_y < 0 or ending_y >= grid_size: continue

                    failed = False


                    for i in range(word_length):
                        character = word[i]

                        new_position_x = x_position + i*step_x
                        new_position_y = y_position + i*step_y

                        character_at_new_position = grid[new_position_x][new_position_y]
                        if character_at_new_position != '_':
                            if character_at_new_position == character:
                                continue
                            else:
                                failed = True
                                break

                    if failed:
                        continue
                    else:
                        for i in range(word_length):
                            character = word[i]

                            new_position_x = x_position + i*step_x
                            new_position_y = y_position + i*step_y

                            grid[new_position_x][new_position_y] = character
                            if ( grid[row][column] == grid[new_position_x][new_position_y] ):
                                grid[row][column] = grid[new_position_x][new_position_y]
                                Label(self, text=character).grid(row=row, column=column)
                        placed = True
                if ( grid[row][column] == '_' ):
                    txt = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
                    Label(self, text=txt).grid(row=row, column=column)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Original console version code:

```
import random
import string

from pprint import pprint

def mainfunc():

    handle = open('dictionary.txt')
    words = handle.readlines()
    handle.close()

    words = [ random.choice(words).upper().strip() \
              for _ in range(5) ]

    grid_size = 20

    grid = [ [ '_' for _ in range(grid_size) ] for _ in range(grid_size) ]

    def print_grid():
        for x in range(grid_size):
            print ('\t' *3 + ' '.join( grid[x] ))

    orientations = [ 'leftright', 'updown', 'diagonalup', 'diagonaldown' ]

    for word in words:
        word_length = len(word)

        placed = False
        while not placed:
            orientation = random.choice(orientations)

            if orientation == 'leftright':
                step_x = 1
                step_y = 0
            if orientation == 'updown':
                step_x = 0
                step_y = 1
            if orientation == 'diagonalup':
                step_x = 1
                step_y = -1
            if orientation == 'diagonaldown':
                step_x = 1
                step_y = 1

            x_position = random.randrange(grid_size)
            y_position = random.randrange(grid_size)

            ending_x = x_position + word_length*step_x
            ending_y = y_position + word_length*step_y

            if ending_x < 0 or ending_x >= grid_size: continue
            if ending_y < 0 or ending_y >= grid_size: continue

            failed = False


            for i in range(word_length):
                character = word[i]

                new_position_x = x_position + i*step_x
                new_position_y = y_position + i*step_y

                character_at_new_position = grid[new_position_x][new_position_y]
                if character_at_new_position != '_':
                    if character_at_new_position == character:
                        continue
                    else:
                        failed = True
                        break

            if failed:
                continue
            else:
                for i in range(word_length):
                    character = word[i]

                    new_position_x = x_position + i*step_x
                    new_position_y = y_position + i*step_y

                    grid[new_position_x][new_position_y] = character

                placed = True

    for x in range(grid_size):
        for y in range(grid_size):
            if ( grid[x][y] == '_' ):
                grid[x][y] = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase)

    print_grid()

    print ("The words are:")
    pprint(words)

mainfunc()
```

List of words for 'dictionary.txt': [here](https://pastebin.com/azRgnZw2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a minor indentation issue.

```
for word in words:
    word_length = len(word)
    placed = False
while not placed:
    <rest of the code>
    ....
```

The for loop is looping over each word, for the WHOLE LIST. When it is done `word` has been assigned the last word in the list. It then continues with the code, only using the final word in your list.

Simply indent the block of code starting with `while not placed`.

```
for word in words:
    word_length = len(word)
    placed = False
    while not placed:
        <rest of the code>
        ....
```

If you compare to your console version, you can see the while loop is properly indented inside the for loop, which is why that works correctly.