# Only 1 item from my array is getting used (all should be used)

Tags: python, tkinter

This program is supposed to make a word search with random letters and 5 words in an array. The program is only using 1 word out of the array but it is supposed to use all 5. Here is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import string

handle = open('dictionary.txt')
words = handle.readlines()
handle.close()

grid_size = 10

words = [ random.choice(words).upper().strip() \
            for _ in range(5) ]

print ("The words are:")
print(words)

grid = [ [ '_' for _ in range(grid_size) ] for _ in range(grid_size) ]

orientations = [ 'leftright', 'updown', 'diagonalup', 'diagonaldown' ]

class Label(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs, font=("Courier", 44))
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_click)

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        for row in range(grid_size):
            for column in range(grid_size):
                for word in words:
                    word_length = len(word)
                    placed = False
                while not placed:
                    orientation = random.choice(orientations)

                    if orientation == 'leftright':
                        step_x = 1
                        step_y = 0
                    if orientation == 'updown':
                        step_x = 0
                        step_y = 1
                    if orientation == 'diagonalup':
                        step_x = 1
                        step_y = -1
                    if orientation == 'diagonaldown':
                        step_x = 1
                        step_y = 1

                    x_position = random.randrange(grid_size)
                    y_position = random.randrange(grid_size)

                    ending_x = x_position + word_length*step_x
                    ending_y = y_position + word_length*step_y

                    if ending_x < 0 or ending_x >= grid_size: continue
                    if ending_y < 0 or ending_y >= grid_size: continue

                    failed = False


                    for i in range(word_length):
                        character = word[i]

                        new_position_x = x_position + i*step_x
                        new_position_y = y_position + i*step_y

                        character_at_new_position = grid[new_position_x][new_position_y]
                        if character_at_new_position != '_':
                            if character_at_new_position == character:
                                continue
                            else:
                                failed = True
                                break

                    if failed:
                        continue
                    else:
                        for i in range(word_length):
                            character = word[i]

                            new_position_x = x_position + i*step_x
                            new_position_y = y_position + i*step_y

                            grid[new_position_x][new_position_y] = character
                            if ( grid[row][column] == grid[new_position_x][new_position_y] ):
                                grid[row][column] = grid[new_position_x][new_position_y]
                                Label(self, text=character).grid(row=row, column=column)
                        placed = True
                if ( grid[row][column] == '_' ):
                    txt = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
                    Label(self, text=txt).grid(row=row, column=column)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

I would also like to add I have a version working that only uses the console (no tkinter) that uses all the words in the array; I can post that if it'd be helpful.

Comment: Is this the exact same issue as in your [earlier today's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60696640)?

Comment: Your `for word in words:` loop contains only two lines in its body.  Everything after that gets executed for a single word, the final one that the loop visited.

Comment: usr2564301, sorry for the confusion, no. If I manually give it a list of words it works fine, but as soon as I plug in the text file it doesn't work.

Comment: jasonharper, thanks I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you simply screwed up indentation. `words` is last used in the 2-line `for` loop `for word in words:`. Bus it seems to me that the line `while not placed:` and a lot of following lines should be part of that loops body.

Does that make sense? I didnt try it out.

Comment: Thanks this seemed to have fixed the initial problem. Now before I create a new question would you happen to know why the words are being used multiple times? The program is fitting in each word to as many spaces as possible instead of just 1 instance of the word. I thought that using the "while not placed" loop would stop this from happening but it does not.

Comment: Hm, this is really hard to tell as I dont know how your code is indented now. I would suggest to re-check your indentation again to see whether `placed = True` is definitely called whenever characters have been placed.